# Is it possible to use reflection directly in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reflection

In my DB I have a table that contains different items of userControls with the attributes "ClassName", "AssemblyName" and "NameSpace" which are necesarry to init the instances using reflection.

My Idea was To get this collection from the DB, set the collection  as the data-context and dynamically load these usercontrols into a tabcontrol. I could use a "tabItem"  which would contain it and in runtime in the code behind load it. I guess it would be really handy and fancy if it could be done directly from XAML in a template.

I've been googleling for something similar, but found nothing without using code behind.

I was thinking something like the following

```
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <xxxControl ClassName="{Binding ClassName}" AssemblyName="{Binding AssemblyName}" NameSpace="{Binding NameSpace}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

I could make such a custom "xxxControl" but it would be a waste of time if something like that already exists. This way The GUI could be completly generated by the parameters in the DB.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a lot of things in XAML using [markup extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254.aspx), in this case you could create one that instantiates controls from the given information. For that it needs some dependency properties that can be bound, and in [`ProvideValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.markupextension.providevalue.aspx) it would then get the assembly, construct the full name and instantiate it.

Usage:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <me:Instance Assembly="{Binding AssemblyName}"
                 NameSpace="{Binding NameSpace}"
                 Class="{Binding ClassName}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Obviously you still have code-behind, but that is how it should be, imperative code does *not* belong in XAML at all.

Also i doubt that your data-base should contain information about UI controls...

Comment: this kind of approach is something I had in mind. I was hoping that something like this already exists in WPF, so I dont have do do it on my own

Comment: true.
What controls would you suggest to inherit from. Usercontrol? TabItem?

Comment: @user853710: You do not create a control but a [`MarkupExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.markupextension.aspx), it is a class that returns something that is then placed where it appears in XAML.

Comment: I did it. nice. Just getting this error while trying to add the reflected class.
Assembly ass = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SubModuleObject.AssemblyName)
                                ? System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(SubModuleObject.AssemblyName)
                                : System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            UserControl x = ass.CreateInstance(string.Format("{0}.{1}", SubModuleObject.NameSpace, SubModuleObject.ClassName)) as UserControl;

            grid.Children.Add(x);

I get the following error
"cannot convert from object to system.windows.UIElement"

Comment: @user853710: As i said, you should just return the user control and not add it to a grid. Also if that error is in your reflection code you should search SO about it, this question should be about the WPF aspects and not how you implement the back-end.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh. Don't control your UI from the database directly.  The closest you should come (assuming you can't make significant architecture changes) IMO would be to load your DB entries into an `IObservable` in your VM and use a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) to translate your collection into UI controls.